# Which is lighter, running Android Virtual Device in WSL2 or Windows?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, android, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My goal is to reduce CPU and memory usage while developing an app.

I was wondering whether I should run everything on WSL2 now. I would like to start from running Android Virtual Device since my laptop heats up easily when I run the Android Virtual Device.

Comment: This is something that should be relatively easy to test and there week be some variation based on system drivers and hardware. So, what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear have not tried it yet. No excuses, I will back within a day after trying it.

Comment: WSL2 is a proper VM. It ought to be more taxing, not less?

Comment: @BeigeTheColor thought so. After some consideration, I believe using Android Virtual Device inside WSL2 would be overkill, so I would not try it. To be fair, I did try it with Docker inside WSL2 tho, it does work faster. Regarding AVD in WSL2, I chose to use physical device and it does mitigate some performance throttle.

Comment: @kidfrom the few android devs I've known also always used physical devices to test with, cuz its way faster.

Comment: Have you tried AVD in WSL2 (or AVD on a Windows where WSL2 is activated)? From my understanding the emulator will be very very very slow, because once HyperV for WSL2 is activated the emulator has no longer access to the hardware virtualization functions provided by the CPU.